# How to pass a char to a function expecting a string

Tags: c++

I want to pass a char to a parameter expecting a string.

```
void test(const string&);

test('a'); // does not like
```

`error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’`

I know I can change ' to ", but in my real code it's not a literal at that point.

How can I conveniently get this to compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no implicit conversion from a character to a string. You'll have to make a string using the appropriate constructor, which has another parameter to specify the length:

```
test(std::string(1, 'a'));
```

or, since C++11, with an initialiser list

```
test({'a'});             // if there are no ambiguous overloads of "test"
test(std::string{'a'});  // if you need to specify the type
```

Comment: I guess there will be warning because of giving temporary object by reference.

Comment: @Arkady: There shouldn't be; passing a temporary by (const) reference is a common thing to do, and I've never heard of any compiler warning about it.

Comment: What about `std::string() + 'a'`, I just thought of?

Comment: @NeilKirk: That would also give the same result, but looks a bit quirky to my eyes.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I've clarified that I meant overloads of `test`. For example, if there were also a `test(vector<char>)`, then an initialiser list would be an equally good match for both overloads.

Answer (score 4):

You could use curly bruckets like the example below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void test(const std::string&) { std::cout << "test!" << std::endl; }

int main() {
  test({'a'});
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b16e7cea374f438)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for message overloading.

```
void test(const string&);
void test(char);
```

and in your class implementation.

```
void yourclass::test(const string& aString)
{
...
}


void yourclass::test(char aChar)
{
  ::test(std::string(1,aChar));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that for every function taking a string, where I might want to pass a char!

Comment: @NeilKirk then don't do it! That you don't want to do it (even though you made no mention of such requirements in your question) doesn't make the answer invalid.

Comment: The word "convenient" is very subjective and many people think overloads are convenient. Consider for example that rather than having many functions to overload (as your comment here implies), you had just the one function and many instances of it being called -- now which is more convenient? Now that you see that point... you'll notice your post makes no mention of how many places such functions are called, or how many functions there are.

Comment: @NeilKirk "I did mention conveniently"... that is a little ambiguous don't you think. Your question asked how to pass a char to a method expecting a string. Given that there does not exist a explicit conversion any answers will have you not passing a char.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, may be add your own overload?

```
void test(char v)
{ test(string(1, v)); }
```

EDIT:
I didn't mention C++11 answers as listed, and I assumed you can't modify the callsites. If the latter is the case and you don't have c++11, then create a macro/function for this..

```
void to_string(char v)
{ return string(1, v); }

// Use
test(to_string('c'));
```

you can then handle all the cases (`const char*`, `char*` etc with overloads of `to_string()`)

Comment: I don't want to do that for every function taking a string, where I might want to pass a char!

Comment: There are many ways solve this problem, but you've not really stated what the constraints are (can you modify the callsites for example, or do you have a specific interface you want to stick to, do you have c++11 - which some answers assume etc.) If you clarify, may be there will be a concensus on what could be a good solution..